# How to restrict app download from play store to certain group of people

Tags: android

I have developed an android app which is a client based application , which can be used only when you have credentials to log in. I  want to upload this on Play Store which can be downloaded by our clients only. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939801/restrict-access-to-download-the-application-on-google-play

Comment: You can use a key. Before downloading or installing the app, the user should have an encrypted key. So clients will have to request the key and then you send them only if they meet your preconditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only targeting your clients, I would upload the apk to a central website that your clients have access to, like your company website. There, clients can download and install your app right off of the website. However, your clients might need to change a security setting to install it from the internet.