# Restrict user to download app

Tags: android, restrict, google-workspace

is it possible to restrict the users that are going to download an app from the play store?

I have seen in the official documentation that you have to have a G Suite account but I just want certain users to be able to install the app

Thanks

Comment: You need to read about android MDM & Kiosk mode. There is no other way to limit user actions

Comment: maybe don't put it in the store. Or make users log in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict access to download the application on Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939801/restrict-access-to-download-the-application-on-google-play)